# Date is disappeared (ASP classic - VB Script)

Tags: internet-explorer, asp-classic, localization, vbscript

I have a little problem but it makes me crazy. I made an application using asp, and I created a text box which would be filled by the date of today. It works well in my computer and the other clients, but some don't. and it always asks to input the date till the clients get bored and no result...

At first I thought that was becaused of the setting of the IE. I've restored to the default setting, but it's big O. now I am fed up with this thing..

what do you think about the causes of this issue?
Kindly need your help...

Regards,

Hery

Comment: what is happening when it doesn't work ?

Comment: Can you post the asp code in question?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably running into localization problems, as you're probably trying to validate that date.

You'll need a more robust way to parse your date at client, or to post it to server to use a browser independent implementation.

Comment: Dear Rubens Farias,

Thanks for your response. 
Anyway, let me describe the code that implemented in that application

<input type="text" name="txt_date" size="20" value="<%= date() %>" style="border: 1px solid #C2E0EC; " readonly="true"/>

The value of txt_date is set up as today. I have tried to the other server and it works well...no malfunction for sure.... The setting for both servers are the same. 
But What's going on with this one server? 
Any idea?

Comment: hmm, seems your second server you dont have ASP enabled; can you check this?